# Highcharts Reflow Heavy Chart Lagging

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-snow-2u310?file=/src/index.js:0-2351)

I use the Reflow API to resize the chart after the sidebar is closed,

it cost a long time to wait for the sidebar closing,

```
const series = [];
const seriesAmount = 200;

for (var i = 0; i < seriesAmount; i++) {
  series.push({});
  series[i].data = [];
  for (var j = 0; j < 288; j++) {
    series[i].data.push(Math.random());
  }
}
const options = {
  series: series
};
```

When seriesAmount < 100, speed is still acceptable,

```
const seriesAmount = 50;
```

but when seriesAmount >=200 || seriesAmount = 300 is very laggy,

```
const seriesAmount = 300;
```

I tried destroy the chart first and then create a new chart, but it doesn't work.

```
const toggleHidden = () => {
  this.setState({
    isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
  });

  Highcharts.charts.forEach((chart, idx, array) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      chart.destroy();
    }, 10);
  });
};
```

Hope there is a way to fix this problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things that you can improve:

1. Series are recalculated in every render. It is better to create them once in a constructor.

---

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  const series = [];
  const seriesAmount = 200;
  for (var i = 0; i < seriesAmount; i++) {
    series.push({});
    series[i].data = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < 288; j++) {
      series[i].data.push(Math.random());
    }
  }

  this.state = {
    isHidden: false,
    chartOptions: {
      series
    }
  };
}
```

---

2. Charts are updated before reflow because of changed state. Set `allowChartUpdate` to false, to prevent that.

---

```
<HighchartsReact
  allowChartUpdate={false}
  highcharts={Highcharts}
  containerProps={{ style: { height: "300px" } }}
  options={this.state.chartOptions}
/>
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-rain-gkyjd?file=/src/index.js

**Docs:** https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#optimal-way-to-update

Comment: Thank you! I will consider about your advices!

Comment: In my case, I'm using react-grid-layout for the card layout. Multiple cards are rendered one below one. Each card renders a graph using a highchart. But when I open my sidebar which contains filters through a toggle CTA. The charts are resizing with lots of lag. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi @Papu Kumar, Please create a new SO question with a more detailed description of the problem and some minimal live example.